# FullCalendar jquery json source parameters

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've a JSON feed which I'm trying to consume with FullCalendar. I can't edit the fields of the json feed but they match 99% what FullCalendar expects. I just need to change fullcalendar so that instead of 'start' for a given event, it will use ' eventStart'

Any ideas? Can't change the feed, but changing fullCalendar should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) says that some modification of parameter names is possible - try playing with the settings in fullcalendar.js

```
var defaults = {

 .... omitted

        startParam: 'start',
        endParam: 'end',
```

Comment: Have tried those already unfortunately, they're related to providing parameters to the feed so you get events between those two dates. The js still expects the feed to contain 'start' rather than anything else. Very frustrating.